# Undefined symbol RealmSwift: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RLMNotificationToken", clang error

Tags: swift, realm, xcode12, undefined-symbol, apple-m1

Hello I'm having this trouble with Realm Swift.

[Having this 4 issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMyak.png)

I'm using M1 Processor and im getting this error after install a private pod named Storage and clean my project.

Storage includes RealmSwift.

Does anyone know hot to fix the issue?

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Please include the error in the question as text.

Comment: Also, your deployment target it set to 8 which is outside what's supported. See the [Minimum Requirements](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/ios-swift/#ios-swift-tutorial). And lastly, I would guess your cocoapods is out of date. You can check in terminal with `pod --version` and it needs to be 1.10.1 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Those are linker errors.  It could be that the libraries haven't been built for M1.  Make sure you've added them as dependencies in `Project Settings` -> your target -> `Frameworks, Libraries & Embedded Content`.  Select and build the libraries individually for M1 to make sure that's not the problem.

You have some compiler warnings in the image you linked, and possibly more above the screenshot. Sorting those out could shed some light on what's going wrong.